# std::thread arguments are copied on the new thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl, std

I have started reading "C++ Concurrency in action, seconds edition" by Anthony Williams. In its 2.2 section he writes that arguments to the thread function are copied on the new thread. I checked this on a couple of compilers, and it is true: if we pass an lvalue - it is copied on the new thread.

Anthony writes that this may represent undefined behaviour - lvalue may go out of scope on the original scope, while new thread starts up.

This is kind of scary. Does this mean that every std::thread constructor invocation has a potential race? Why this copying is not synchronized prior to returning from std::thread constructor? Why it is not copied on the original thread altogether?

Comment: The copy is done in the "main" thread, and there is synchronisation. (See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

Comment: @Mat: May you have some time to take a closer look on it? As I have checked ( see my answer ), the implicit conversion is done inside the newly created thread which is not what I expect by reading the text on cppreference. Do I have some misunderstanding by reading the cppreference? Anthony seems to be right as my example shows the same result as Anthony explains.

Answer (score 1):

From: [std::thread::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

> Except that the calls to decay_copy are evaluated in the context of the caller, so that any exceptions thrown during evaluation and copying/moving of the arguments are thrown in the current thread, without starting the new thread.
> The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes-with (as defined in std::memory_order) the beginning of the invocation of the copy of f on the new thread of execution.

That describes that all the copy actions are done *before* thread starts execution.

But lets test!

If we run this short example:

```
class CopyMe
{
    private:
        std::string s;
    public:
        CopyMe() = default;
        CopyMe( const CopyMe& ) { std::cout << "CATCH Copy Me" << std::endl; }
        CopyMe( CopyMe&& ) { std::cout << "CATCH Moved" << std::endl; }
        CopyMe( const char* s_ ):s{s_}{ std::cout << "CATCH Implicit conversion" << std::endl; }
};

void Run( CopyMe )
{
    std::cout << "CATCH Thread context" << std::endl; 
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "CATCH Main Context" << std::endl;
    CopyMe me; 
    std::thread t( Run, "Hallo");
    t.join();
}
```

with `strace -xfo dump prog`

and grep for our output, we get:

```
6071  write(1, "CATCH Main Context\n", 19) = 19
6072  write(1, "CATCH Implicit conversion\n", 26) = 26
6072  write(1, "CATCH Thread context\n", 21) = 21
```

Ubs! We see that the part of implicit conversion is done inside the newly created thread!

Comment: The arg you passed to the std::thread constructor is a pointer to char. That pointer gets copied before the new thread is started, and there is no problem with your example code. If you pass a pointer to a temporary/local variable, then yes you can get undefined behavior - but that's not specific to std::thread, you'd get that passing it to anything that attempts to hold on to the pointer and use it later.

Comment: @Mat: For clarification: The text on cppreference means: All args are copied before the call which means in my example, we get a copy of the pointer to const char. BUT the implicit conversion takes place in the newly created thread from the already copied pointer... I am right now?

Comment: Yes. It is the arguments you give to `std::thread`'s constructor that get copied. The call to your function (including "creating" its arguments if necessary) happens on the new thread.